# cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation Error

Tags: cordova-plugins

After Adding **cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation** build Error Occurs

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

Below, links to working GitHub project that use mauron85-background-geolocation-example-server.

- [mauron85-background-geolocation-example-server](https://github.com/oliviercherrier/mauron85-background-geolocation-example-server): REST API for storing locations provided by mauron85-background-geolocation plugin
- [mauron85-background-geolocation-example-ionic2](https://github.com/oliviercherrier/mauron85-background-geolocation-example-ionic2): Demonstration application which communicate with  mauron85-background-geolocation-example-server.

Hope it could help.